# Reverse polarity with feedback

Tags: reverse-polarity

The below is a reverse polarity circuit with additional components around it. I would like to understand the exact functionality of the additional circuitry in dotted lines.

[image]

Comment: Ravi Prasad - Hi, Re: "*I came across the following reverse polarity circuit*" Where did you come across it? To comply with the [site rule on referencing](/help/referencing), you should include a suitable citation for material copied or adapted and posted on Stack Exchange. For an online source, adding the webpage / PDF / video title & its link are the minimum; see the rule above for more details. Please [edit] your question to add a suitable reference. || Please see the [tour] & [help] as the site rules differ from typical forums. TY

Comment: Please double-check your source. It looks like Q2 should be PNP rather than NPN. As an NPN, there is no source for its base current. But as a PNP (emitter connected to Vout), it would actively clamp the gate of M1 in the off state as soon as Q1 turns on as a result of Vin becoming less than Vout.

Comment: Hi Dave, BC846BPN chip contains npn pnp transistors. Connections are same exactly shown circuit.

Comment: I understand that, but it still doesn't make sense to use a NPN in that position.